# Is it possible to call local storage inside a function and use it in Windows.onload?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a on click function which  return 'x' and stores in div dynamically. After a page refresh, this dynamic div resets and the data is gone. But i want the data to stay. To do that i stored that in local storage and want to call later when page loads. I store it in local storage inside the function 'test'
and calling it in windows.onload which is returning null. I understand that i am unable to call the local storage inside the function. My question: Is there a way to call the local storage inside the function 'test'

```
function test(parameter1, parameter2) { // this is an onclick function
    
// some functionality
        
 return x;
 var test = x.innerHTML;
 localStorage.setItem('somediv', test);

}

window.onload = function () {

    var test2 = localStorage.getItem('somediv')
    $('div.somediv').text(test2);


}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is a real problem? Have you actually tried this or is it theoretical? The only potential issue you have is calling `return x;` before the doing anything else and the following lines won't be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `localStorage` fine.

The thing is, if you `return x;` in your `text()` function, the code below is never executed, so it never actually sets the `localStorage` variable.

That is why you get `null` when you are trying to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you will get an idea.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="test('hello brother')">Click me</a>
    
    <script>
    function test(param) { // this is an onclick function
        localStorage.setItem('somediv', param);
        alert('ok');
    }
    
    window.onload = function () {
    
        if(localStorage.getItem('somediv')==null){
            return;
        }
        var test2 = localStorage.getItem('somediv')
        //$('div.somediv').text(test2);
    
        alert(test2);
    
    }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: This helped me to understand it better. Thank You.